# Using DISTINCT and COUNT together in a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is something like this possible:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(productId) WHERE keyword='$keyword'
```

What I want is to get the number of unique product Ids which are associated with a keyword. The same product may be associated twice with a keyword, or more, but i would like only 1 time to be counted per product ID

Answer (score 308, accepted):

use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productId) from  table_name WHERE keyword='$keyword'
```

Comment: Updated the answer as it is close to become a great answer and it was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Im against answers that don't offer optimal performance when it comes to databases. It's critical to keep perfomance standards. I'd go with @alistair-hart 's answer.

Comment: Stumbled across this while looking for something else and learned something. I've always done this with `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(productId)) from  table_name WHERE keyword='$keyword'`. I like your version better passing two params to `COUNT( )`.

Comment: To my surprise, I found that there cannot be a space between "COUNT" and the opening parenthesis - at least in version 10.1.41 of MariaDB.

Answer (score 71):

I would do something like this:

```
Select count(*), productid
from products
where keyword = '$keyword'
group by productid
```

that will give you a list like

```
count(*)    productid  
----------------------
 5           12345   
 3           93884   
 9           93493
```

This allows you to see how many of each distinct productid ID is associated with the keyword.

Answer (score 41):

You were close :-)

```
select count(distinct productId) from table_name where keyword='$keyword'
```

Comment: Updated the answer as it is close to become a good answer and it was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 25):

FYI, this is probably faster,

```
SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT distinct productId WHERE keyword = '$keyword') temp
```

than this,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productId) WHERE keyword='$keyword'
```

Comment: Not sure if it's faster, but the way to count multiple columns with distinct keyword

Comment: Fantastic answer. His answer is at least 100 times more faster in my case. A slight alteration for understanding @Alistair's code is `SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT distinct productId WHERE keyword = '$keyword') temp`

Answer (score 9):

**What the hell of all this work anthers**

it's too simple

if you want a list of how much productId in each keyword here it's the code

```
SELECT count(productId),  keyword  FROM `Table_name` GROUP BY keyword;
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment, not the purist answer to his exact question, but maybe what he's looking for, and anyway useful.

Answer (score 6):

## SELECTING DISTINCT PRODUCT AND DISPLAY COUNT PER PRODUCT

for another answer about this type of question, this is my way of getting the count of product based on their product name using distinct. Here a sample:

**List of Product** ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e8ba9/1)):

```
select * FROM Product
```

[image]

**Product Name Count Using Distinct** ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e8ba9/24)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Product_Name),
(SELECT COUNT(Product_Name) 
from Product  WHERE Product_Name = Prod.Product_Name)  
as `Product_Count`
from Product as Prod
```

**Optimized version without Distinct**:

```
SELECT Product_Name, COUNT(Product_Name) AS `Product_Count`
FROM Product
GROUP BY Product_Name
```

[image]

Answer (score -6):

Isn't it better with a group by?
Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 GROUP BY keywork;
```

Comment: He wants the number of distinct productID's. Your query returns the number of rows for each keyword.