# How to select distinct from just one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a table with the following structure

```
view_id | user_agent | view_date | post_id | user_id
```

I would like to do a view-count for each post, however if a particular user read a particular article more than once it still considered as 1 viewcount.

So far i have come up with this simple query

```
SELECT member_id, COUNT(member_id) AS view_count
FROM gw_library_viewcount
WHERE DATE(view_date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
GROUP BY member_id;
```

However it returns the number of viewcount for each individual user for today. Then i edit it so it becomes

```
SELECT COUNT(member_id) AS view_count
FROM gw_library_viewcount
WHERE DATE(view_date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
```

This time the query returns the total number of view_count, however it includes multiple viewcount. I only want it to returns the number of viewcount for each post with a condition that if there is a user who view the article more than once, it still considered as one viewcount.

How can i achieve this result?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try `COUNT(DISTINCT member_id)`.

That is,:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM gw_library_viewcount WHERE ... GROUP BY post_id;
```

Note, not sure if it should be `member_id` or `user_id`, since you have used it interchangeably in your question.

For example, see [Using DISTINCT and COUNT together in a MySQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query).

Comment: My bad, it is suppose to be member_id.

Comment: +1 although you should probably include `post_id` into the selection list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to select unique post views, something like this:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(member_id) AS view_count
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT member_id, post_id, MAX(view_date) AS view_date
     FROM gw_library_viewcount
     GROUP BY member_id, post_id
) t
WHERE DATE(view_date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
GROUP BY post_id
```

**Edit:** Removed non-sensical group by MAX(view_date) from subquery based upon OP feedback

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried your query it works (well almost) i had to modify it a bit by removing the "MAX(view_date)" group_by.

Comment: Glad I could help, I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gareththegeek, by modifying his answer a bit i can resolve this. This is the query i am looking for.

The subquery basically is to show what article each member has read for a particular day (multiple visit/read still counts as one)

So it returns result like this:

```
member id | post id | view_date
1 ---------> 1 ------> some_date 
1 ---------> 2 ------> some_date
3 ---------> 1 ------> some_date
```

and so on....

From here, the i simply count the number of users. Anyway this seems to be working so far.. again thx to gareththegeek.

```
SELECT COUNT(member_id) AS view_count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT member_id, post_id, MAX(view_date) AS view_date
    FROM gw_library_viewcount
    WHERE DATE(view_date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
    GROUP BY member_id, post_id
) AS subquery
```

*** Previous query

The result of the query below turns out only valid if given interval is 0. When tested with other value such as 1 (representing Yesterday), it gives inaccurate result.

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(member_id) AS view_count
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT member_id, post_id, MAX(view_date) AS view_date
     FROM gw_library_viewcount
     GROUP BY member_id, post_id
) t
WHERE DATE(view_date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
GROUP BY post_id
```