# Aggregating across multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I thought I had this figured out, but it's eluding me. There's a MySQL database backending a web app that collects user surveys of various theme parks. There's a series of 30 questions, some have radio-button style multiple choice and some are checkbox-style. The responses are all stored in a relational table that resembles this:

```
"id"|"q_id"| "a_id"|"u_id"                              |"p_id"| 
 "1"|   "1"|    "1"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"106397"|
 "2"|   "1"|    "2"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"106397"|
 "3"|   "2"|    "1"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"106397"|
 "4"|   "3"|    "1"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"106397"|
 "7"|   "3"|    "3"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"106397"|
 "8"|   "3"|    "4"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"106397"|
 "9"|   "1"|    "2"|"348895be7b4affac001c9ba096d8c1d3"|"106397"|
"10"|   "1"|    "3"|"348895be7b4affac001c9ba096d8c1d3"|"106397"|
"11"|   "3"|    "2"|"348895be7b4affac001c9ba096d8c1d3"|"106397"|
"13"|   "3"|    "3"|"348895be7b4affac001c9ba096d8c1d3"|"106397"| 
 "1"|   "1"|    "3"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"380486"|
 "3"|   "2"|    "2"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"380486"|
 "4"|   "3"|    "2"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"380486"|
 "7"|   "3"|    "4"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"380486"|
 "8"|   "3"|    "4"|"8f699ecbd9f130df14c1e4e0a6383516"|"380486"|
"11"|   "3"|    "2"|"348895be7b4affac001c9ba096d8c1d3"|"380486"|
"13"|   "3"|    "3"|"348895be7b4affac001c9ba096d8c1d3"|"380486"|
```

q_id is the question answered
a_id is the option chosen
u_id is the user that chose the option
p_id is the amusement park they answered the question

Thus, this table may contain multiple records where u_id, q_id and p_id are the same in the case of a checkbox-style question, but never one where u_id, q_id, p_id and a_id are the same.

What I need to do is create a query that will give me a count of the total number of times each given question has been answered for a given amusement park. In this case, what I'd need is:

```
  "p_id"|"count" 
"106397"|"5"
"380486"|"4"
```

...in other words, I need each p_id, with a count of the number of unique instances of both q_id and u_id. I thought this would work:

```
SELECT distinct p_id, count(concat(q_id,u_id)) from responses group by p_id
```

But that still seems to be counting two records that have the same values for q_id and u_id but different values of a_id twice, giving me:

```
  "p_id"|"count" 
"106397"|"10"
"380486"| "7"
```

What can I do to this query to make this aggregate function work?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query It might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluefeet's answer is definitely one way to go.  This is how you modify your approach to make it work:

```
SELECT p_id, count(distinct concat(q_id,':',u_id))
from responses
group by p_id;
```

These are the changes that I made:

1. Removed the `distinct` in `select distinct`.  This is (generally) redundant with a `group by`.
2. Changed the `count()` to `count(distinct)`.  You want to count distinct occurrence of this pair.
3. Added a separator.  That way (23, 4) doesn't get confused with (2, 34).  Just in case.

Comment: The separator is a good idea; likely unnecessary in this case because u_id is a 32-character hash and q_id is an integer, but I'm going to do it just for the sake of edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use the following query which uses a subquery to get the total count of each distinct `u_id` grouped by `p_id` and `q_id`, then you can apply the `sum()` aggregate function to the subquery result:

```
select p_id, sum(total) Total
from
(
  select p_id, q_id, count(distinct u_id) total
  from responses
  group by p_id, q_id
) d
group by p_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f601c/14)

Comment: This answer definitely works, though Linoff's answer seems like a simpler way to accomplish the same thing; both end with the same results, though.