# Mysql distinct with count with condition

Tags: php, mysql

having [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query) in mind

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productId) WHERE keyword='$keyword'
```

How can I get count of distinct row by condition

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productId -- THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PUT CONDITION --) WHERE keyword='$keyword'
```

I need to cont distinct rows if that row doesn't have `type <> 1`

Comment: If you need distinct productId and multiple exist - which row to take - it can be important because rows having the same productid can have different types values

Comment: Does the condition necessarily have to to be inside the `COUNT` function?

Comment: I want all records to be selected, because I'm doing calculation on them, I just don't want count of products if they have type 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but are you looking for this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productId) from table_name WHERE keyword='$keyword' and type!=1
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN type <> 1 
                           THEN productId 
                      ELSE NULL 
                      END
             ) 
FROM table_name
WHERE keyword='$keyword'
```

Comment: no I want all records to be selected, because I'm doing calculation on them, I just don't want count of prodcuts if they have type 1

Comment: @tinybyte:- You may use the CASE then. See the update

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is an issue with modifying the `WHERE` clause, you can use [`CASE operator`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) or [`IF function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN type <> 1 THEN productId ELSE NULL END) 
FROM <table>
WHERE keyword = '<keyword>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra condition goes in the `WHERE` clause, not in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productId)
WHERE keyword = '$keyword'
AND type != 1
```