# MYSQL most efficient / simplest way to count different values in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

Customers rent cars, cars are grouped in different categories, 'A - D'

The following queries gets entered to display all vehicle groups rented throughout 2016.

`SELECT car_group FROM rentals WHERE checkout_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30'`

The output is as follows:

[image]

Now I could run the query and sort the groups via some PHP but I am sure it will be more efficient using a mysql statement...?

I know I can use `SELECT count(car_group) as cars` but that will return the total sum of cars NOT the amount of different groups.

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: You may try combining `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: I think you need `count(distinct car_group)`. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query