# Count Query Results But Limit To 1 Result Per Col Value

Tags: mysql

I have a visitor tracking script... It stores various info including the session id

I want to be able to count the daily figures but ONLY count 1 record per session id

How would I write the query .. 
The session id col is `sessionid`

Basic query ex:
SELECT * FROM `imps` WHERE `dd`='$dd' AND `mm`='$mm' AND `yyyy`='$yyyy '

Would I do a GROUP_BY & limit 1 ?

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT...

Comment: Perfect 
I just tried ...

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessionid) from  imps WHERE dd='$dd' AND mm='$mm' AND yyyy='$yyyy '

Thanks man !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DISTINCT and COUNT together in a MySQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessionid) from imps WHERE dd='$dd' AND mm='$mm' AND yyyy='$yyyy '
```

Just what I wanted !
Thanks @Maciej Kwas

Found the solution & query structure here
[Using DISTINCT and COUNT together in a MySQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query)