# Add COUNT and DISTINCT in $query

Tags: php, mysql

How to add select COUNT and DISTINCT in the below $query? Please let me know if you need any other details to solve this issue. Thank you for your time.

```
if(isset($_POST["intake_year"]))
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM marketing_data
 WHERE intake_year = '".$_POST["intake_year"]."'
 ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output[] = array(
   'semester'   => $row["semester"],
   'student_matric'  => floatval($row["count"])
  );
 }
 echo json_encode($output);
}
```

//SELECT count(student_matric) AS count, semester, intake_year FROM marketing_data GROUP BY intake_year - This query is to only COUNT student_matric

//SELECT DISTINCT semester FROM marketing_data ORDER BY semester DESC - This query is to only DISTINCT semester

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002349/using-distinct-and-count-together-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: But my count and distinct isn't for the same column... Please refer to the command //

Comment: I understand, but the column can be changed. Your question was how to use `count` and `distinct` in the same query.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like that

`$query = "
 SELECT distinct semester , count(student_matric) as count FROM marketing_data
 WHERE intake_year = '".$_POST["intake_year"]."'
Group by student_matric " ;`